# Is Σ* a context free language

Tags: context-free-grammar

Is Σ∗ a context free grammar?
Because I wonder if I can use it to prove that if "For every language
A,if A is not context-free, then A is not context-free."

Comment: This question does not appear to be related to programming but please check out [cs.se] or [cstheory.se].

Comment: `Σ∗` is regular language that includes all strings consists of  `Σ` symbols

Answer (score 2):

The language Σ* isn't a context-free grammar (a CFG is a set of rules that define a language; Σ* is a language), but it is a context-free language. There are a number of ways to see this:

- You could define a CFG for it. Create a simple grammar with production rules S → aS for each character a ∈ Σ, plus one last rule S → ε to stop the recursion.
- You could define a PDA for it. Have a single state which is accepting and which has a loop back to itself on any character, completely ignoring the stack.
- You can note that it's regular - Σ* is a regular expression for itself - and that all regular languages are context-free.

As to your follow-up question about whether you can use it to prove that particular statement, I assume there's a typo in what you've written there because as written it's the same statement implying itself. If you meant to say "if a language is not context-free, then it's not regular," that's true and follows from the contrapositive of the last bullet point.